# Numerical regression testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, regression-testing

I'm working on a scientific computing code (written in C++), and in addition to performing unit tests for the smaller components, I'd like to do regression testing on some of the numerical output by comparing to a "known-good" answer from previous revisions. There are a few features I'd like:

- Allow comparing numbers to a specified tolerance (for both roundoff error and looser expectations)
- Ability to distinguish between ints, doubles, etc, and to ignore text if necessary
- Well-formatted output to tell what went wrong and where: in a multi-column table of data, only show the column entry that differs
- Return `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` depending on whether the files match

Are there any good scripts or applications out there that do this, or will I have to roll my own in Python to read and compare output files? Surely I'm not the first person with these kind of requirements.

*[The following is not strictly relevant, but it may factor into the decision of what to do. I use CMake and its embedded CTest functionality to drive unit tests that use the Google Test framework. I imagine that it shouldn't be hard to add a few `add_custom_command` statements in my `CMakeLists.txt` to call whatever regression software I need.]*

Comment: Most of what you're describing are standard features of unit testing.  Are you asking for something above and beyond unittest?

Comment: Unit testing as I understand it looks at minimal tests with a priori answers. (If I write a function returnTwo that's designed to return a value of two, I can make a unit test to check that the return value is correct.) Regression testing as I mean it is to generate data at a much higher level, and compare the data generated by future revisions with that older data.

Comment: Sorry, your impression of regression testing isn't very helpful.  You don't compare this version against a previous version.  You compare both versions against known good results. It's always possible to create a unit test that has a "magical" answer gleaned from the previous version without explanation.  This can serve as a check that a previous version's results are preserved even if no one knows whether or not they're correct.

Comment: I hate to sound argumentative, but regression testing in scientific computing -- where the approximate answer to a partial differential equation may be affected by discretization error, roundoff error from floating point calculations, statistical error, incomplete convergence, etc. -- is different than in other computing fields *where exact answers exist*. Even though I have "benchmark" data to eight digits for a hundred data points, to solve them myself to that precision would take hours. Thus, my regression tests would compare to a previously found, less precise approximation.

Comment: @SethJohnson I think S Lott meant exactly what you said. He was suggesting to think of your regression test as a unit test; and have the unit test verify that the new version's results are close enough to the new version's results (where the concept of "close enough" is part of the unit test, and can be as complicated as desired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Python script to do more or less what I wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
from optparse import OptionParser
from math import fabs

splitPattern = re.compile(r',|\s+|;')

class FailObject(object):
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = options
        self.failure = False

    def fail(self, brief, full = ""):
        print ">>>> ", brief
        if options.verbose and full != "":
            print "     ", full
        self.failure = True


    def exit(self):
        if (self.failure):
            print "FAILURE"
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            print "SUCCESS"
            sys.exit(0)

def numSplit(line):
    list = splitPattern.split(line)
    if list[-1] == "":
        del list[-1]

    numList = [float(a) for a in list]
    return numList

def softEquiv(ref, target, tolerance):
    if (fabs(target - ref) <= fabs(ref) * tolerance):
        return True

    #if the reference number is zero, allow tolerance
    if (ref == 0.0):
        return (fabs(target) <= tolerance)

    #if reference is non-zero and it failed the first test
    return False

def compareStrings(f, options, expLine, actLine, lineNum):
    ### check that they're a bunch of numbers
    try:
        exp = numSplit(expLine)
        act = numSplit(actLine)
    except ValueError, e:
#        print "It looks like line %d is made of strings (exp=%s, act=%s)." \
#                % (lineNum, expLine, actLine)
        if (expLine != actLine and options.checkText):
            f.fail( "Text did not match in line %d" % lineNum )
        return

    ### check the ranges
    if len(exp) != len(act):
        f.fail( "Wrong number of columns in line %d" % lineNum )
        return

    ### soft equiv on each value
    for col in range(0, len(exp)):
        expVal = exp[col]
        actVal = act[col]
        if not softEquiv(expVal, actVal, options.tol):
            f.fail( "Non-equivalence in line %d, column %d" 
                    % (lineNum, col) )
    return

def run(expectedFileName, actualFileName, options):
    # message reporter
    f = FailObject(options)

    expected  = open(expectedFileName)
    actual    = open(actualFileName)
    lineNum   = 0

    while True:
        lineNum += 1
        expLine = expected.readline().rstrip()
        actLine = actual.readline().rstrip()

        ## check that the files haven't ended,
        #  or that they ended at the same time
        if expLine == "":
            if actLine != "":
                f.fail("Tested file ended too late.")
            break
        if actLine == "":
            f.fail("Tested file ended too early.")
            break

        compareStrings(f, options, expLine, actLine, lineNum)

        #print "%3d: %s|%s" % (lineNum, expLine[0:10], actLine[0:10])

    f.exit()

################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser(usage = "%prog [options] ExpectedFile NewFile")
    parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                      action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                      help="Don't print status messages to stdout")

    parser.add_option("--check-text",
                      action="store_true", dest="checkText", default=False,
                      help="Verify that lines of text match exactly")

    parser.add_option("-t", "--tolerance",
                      action="store", type="float", dest="tol", default=1.e-15,
                      help="Relative error when comparing doubles")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) != 2:
        print "Usage: numdiff.py EXPECTED ACTUAL"
        sys.exit(1)

    run(args[0], args[1], options)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should go for [PyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/pyunit.html#USING), which is now part of the standard lib under the name [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html). It supports everything you asked for. The tolerance check, e.g., is done with [`assertAlmostEqual()`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear earlier, but the code I'm checking is not Python code. I would be writing an external Python script to read in a data file and check values there.

Comment: In that case scipy might help in reading in the data: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput

Answer (score 0):

The [ndiff](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/ndiff/) utility may be close to what you're looking for: it's like diff, but it will compare text files of numbers to a desired tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm quite late to the party, but a few months ago I wrote the [nrtest](https://nrtest.readthedocs.org) utility in an attempt to make this workflow easier. It sounds like it might help you too.

Here's a quick overview. Each test is defined by its input files and its expected output files. Following execution, output files are stored in a portable benchmark directory. A second step then compares this benchmark to a reference benchmark. A recent update has enabled user extensions, so you can define comparison functions for your custom data.

I hope it helps.